# match all rows between all files in a directory

Tags: r, data.table

I have about 150 files in a directory which are replicates of the same experiment, but there's variations between them in terms of the number of rows

They all have the following format

```
Chr,Bases          
chr1,189           
chr1,1465             
chr1,7845           
chr1,12844
```

I wanted to keep 'Bases' that appear in each file, so where rows for any particular file are also in every other file.
I thought the easiest way to do this would be to take the file with the smallest number of rows, and use it to match rows in the other files

```
library(data.table)
#get smallest file
smallest.file <- data.table(read.table='smallest_file.txt', header=T, sep=',')
setkey(smallest.file, Bases)
#get others
other.files <- list.files(pattern="*.bed", full.names=T)

#function to match Bases between those in the smallest file
#and the others
match_bases <- function (i)  {
others <- data.table(read.table(i, header=T, sep=','))
setkey(others, Bases)
match_result <- smallest.file[others, allow.cartesian=TRUE] [
Bases==Bases, list(Chr=Chr, Bases)]
#write results to a new file
this_file <- paste0(i, ".csv")
write.table(bases, file=this_file, sep=',', row.names=F, quote=F)
}


sapply(other.files, match_bases) #preform function for each file
```

And that seems to work.

However I realized after, I have a problem that the rows that are  missing are random, so some rows in the 'smallest file' are also unique to that file and not seen in the others.

Therefore I thought a second approach I could use would be to merge all the files and to keep rows that are duplicated 150 times (they are seen in each file)

I looked at the `duplicated()` function to do this, but I don't see a way that this would be possible. I think it might not be the most efficient way either.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could work, the idea is to merge all the data frames using all=T so that NAs will be added if a value is missing, and remove any line that has an NA:

```
library(data.table)
#get the files
files<- list.files(".", pattern="*.txt")

#read them in a list
data <- lapply(files, function(x){fread(x,header=T,sep=",")})
#rename the Chr colum to Chr_nameoffile
mapply(function(x,y){setnames(y,c(paste("Chr_",x,sep=""),"Bases"))},files,data)



#merge all the data frames
mergedData<-Reduce(function(...) merge(...,all=T,by="Bases"),data)

#Take only those without NAs
mergedData<-mergedData[apply(mergedData,1,function(x){sum(is.na(x))==0}),]

#split the data frame into files of the correct name, using the Chr_nameoffile column
for (i in 2:ncol(mergedData)){
      fileToWrite<-paste("new",unlist(strsplit(colnames(mergedData[,c(1,i),with=F])[2],"_"))[2],sep="_")
      write.table(mergedData[,c(i,1),with=F], file=fileToWrite, sep=',', row.names=F, quote=F)
}
```

Comment: very good idea, just tried it. Unfortunately my files are very large and R tells me it "cannot allocate vector of size 4.4Gb"

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with bash or python but if you are, the `multijoin` script found [here](https://github.com/agordon/bin_scripts) could do the same thing (it joins multiple files based on a column and lets you set a 'filler' if some of the files don't have a row)